# SSRS: extra blank page for hidden data region (subreport wrapped in Rectangle) in PDF exported file

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Ok, below is the code for main report **"Dummy.rdl"**

It has A4 size body and two subreports inside: **"Dummy_A4Sub1.rdl"**, **"Dummy_A4Sub2.rdl"**
Both subreports also have A4 size bodies and are wrapped by **"Rectangle1"** and **"Rectangle2"** respectively  within main report.

Despite that "Hidden" property within "Visibility" tag is set "True" for both **"Dummy_A4Sub2"** and **"Rectangle2"** data regions, an extra page is being generated at the end.

Any suggestions? What have I missed?
Thanks in advance!

**"Dummy.rdl"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Rectangle Name="Rectangle1">
        <ReportItems>
          <Subreport Name="Subreport1">
            <ReportName>Dummy_A4Sub1</ReportName>
            <Height>5.845in</Height>
            <Width>8.27in</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Subreport>
        </ReportItems>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Height>5.845in</Height>
        <Width>8.27in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Rectangle>
      <Rectangle Name="Rectangle2">
        <ReportItems>
          <Subreport Name="Subreport2">
            <ReportName>Dummy_A4Sub2</ReportName>
            <Height>5.845in</Height>
            <Width>8.27in</Width>
            <Visibility>
              <Hidden>true</Hidden>
            </Visibility>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Subreport>
        </ReportItems>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Top>5.845in</Top>
        <Height>5.845in</Height>
        <Width>8.27in</Width>
        <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
        <Visibility>
          <Hidden>true</Hidden>
        </Visibility>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Rectangle>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>11.69in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>8.27in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeight>11.69in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>85c64ecf-0c52-4234-8ca8-81e36368f77d</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

**"Dummy_A4Sub1.rdl"** (**"Dummy_A4Sub2.rdl"** is similar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>Dummy Subreport1 A4 Size</Value>
                <Style>
                  <FontSize>36pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
        <Top>1.24875in</Top>
        <Left>0.62375in</Left>
        <Height>1.94792in</Height>
        <Width>7.09375in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>11.69in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>8.27in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeight>11.69in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>cfe4adb4-64c8-4225-83e2-abe05f3ba706</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

6 days, 23 view and nothing. But OK, I've managed to solve this by myself.
For anyone, who's facing with the same problem, - here's a solution.

Instead of wrapping subreports with Rectangles (to achive Visibility and Space reducing goal)
wrap them with Tablix:"
1. Create new Table
2. Point on its cell, Right Click, Insert Subreport
3. Right click on Tablix's row. contaiting inserted Subreport, which needs to be hidden, "Row Visibility...". Here you can hide Subreport and prevent SSRS from arranging empty sheet for it.
But more likely you'd like to hide it based on some logical condition

Comment: Hi dexter, what is the datasource of tablix in this case??

Comment: Hi Nikhil, this particular example is dummy (which shows that there might be difficulties with proper rendering of 2 subreports of A4, both static and have no associated data sources). If you need to archive something like that - you may use any data source you have within your project. SSRS requires for tablix some data source just to compile the report. 
However, if you need to use somehow some data from some data source within this Tablix wrapper (let's say to pass this data to Subreports through the parameters) - then obviously, you need to link correspondent Data Source to Tablix

Comment: Hi Dexter i already give the temporary dataset and it is works fine thanks for your comment.